# Accessing the value from controller in directive when the value changes in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created this jsfiddle to illustrate my issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/84/

HTML :

```
    <button ng-click="toggleAwesome()">My awsomw button</button>
    <br />
    {{awesome}}
    <br />

    With template: <example-directive1 awesome="awesome">{{message}}</example-directive1>    

    <br />

    Without template: <example-directive2>{{message}}</example-directive2> 
</div>
```

JS :
    var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'hello';
    $scope.awesome = false;

    $scope.toggleAwesome = function(){
        if($scope.awesome){ $scope.awesome = false; }
        else { $scope.awesome = true; }
    };
}

app.directive('exampleDirective1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<span></span>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            awesome:'='
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.awesome);
            scope.$watch(scope.awesome,function(){ console.log(scope.awesome); })                      
        }
    };
});


app.directive('exampleDirective2', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

        }
    };
});
```

Is there a way to know when the `awesome` gets modify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see here http://jsfiddle.net/E32A2/ just instead $watch(scope.awesome .. 
use  scope.$watch('awesome' ...

```
 app.directive('exampleDirective1', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<span> {{awesome}}</span>',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                awesome: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
                console.log(this.awesome);
                scope.$watch('awesome', function (value) {
                    console.log(value);
                })
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change `$watch` to:

```
  scope.$watch(function(){return scope.awesome;},
           function(newV){
            console.log(newV);
        })
```

The advantage of this statement `function(){return scope.awesome;}` - you don't need worry about spelling. I think to write it as string might lead to unexpected errors like *"suddenly watcher stopped to work"*

Fixed <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/85/)</kbd>

---